# postgresql: postgresq create random integer between null to 100

Tags: postgresql

I want to generate a table with 1000 rows of

```
-- random int between `1-100` (including 1 and 100)
-- random int between `1-100` and also null (including 1 and 100)
-- random float between `0-100` (including 0 and 100)
-- random float between `0-100`and also null (including 0 and 100)
-- random Male (M) and Female (F) i.e M/F values
-- random Male (M) and Female (F) including null/empty i.e M/F values
-- random names of cities from a list (i.e newyork, london, mumbai, dubai etc)
-- random names of cities from a list including null/empty (i.e newyork, london, mumbai, dubai etc)
```

Currently I know

```
create table foo as select random() as test,
from generate_series(1,1000) s(i);
```

How can I do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiplication and type casts or `CASE` expressions.

To get an `integer` between 42 and 1001:

```
42 + CAST (floor(random() * 960) AS integer)
```

I cannot think of a way to generate a `double precision` value that includes the upper bound, but then you never need that with `double precision`.

To get `m` or `f` evenly distributed:

```
CASE WHEN random() < 0.5 THEN `m` ELSE `f` END
```

For the cities, select a random entry from a lookup table.

Comment: thank you. Also i want to add some null values or empty string inbetween.

Comment: Put them in the lookup table.

Comment: I mean for the `42 + CAST (floor(random() * 9960) AS integer)` (also accomodate some null values

Comment: Generate values up to 1002 and use `nullif`.